# EiNotation Question: if $a, b \in \mathbb{Z} - \{0\}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, notation

I just started self studying Abstract Algebra and I came across the following notation;

> if $a, b \in \mathbb{Z} - \{0\}$.

I understand all but the "... $- \{0\}$", I have not seen that in my limit mathematical experience, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Edit for context

The above notation first appear in the following;
if $a, b \in \mathbb{Z} - \{0\}$, there is a unique positive integer d, called the greates common divisor of a and b (or g.c.d. of a and b),...

Comment: first thought is maybe that just means that they both have non-zero absolute value ?

Comment: The notation $A-B$ for the difference of two sets $A$ and $B$ means just $A\setminus B$, that is the set of elements that belong to $A$ but not to $B$.

Comment: In addition to the answers: this is often written as $\mathbb{Z}^*$, meaning (in group theory) the elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ which have an inverse (that is $\mathbb{Z}-\{0\}$).

Answer (score 2):

This means set subtraction: you take all of $\mathbb{Z}$ and subtract the set $\{0\}$, leaving all nonzero integers.

Answer (score 2):

For two sets $A,B$, $$A\setminus B$$ sometimes written $$A-B$$ is a notation for the set $$\{ x\in A : x\notin B\}$$ i.e. the subset of $A$ obtained by removing all elements of $B$. In your case, $\mathbb{Z}-\{0\}$ means "all non-zero elements of $\mathbb{Z}$."

---

$\LaTeX$ note: the symbol for $\setminus$ is `\setminus`, which is quite explicit about what it means.

Answer (score 1):

The minus sign here means "set difference", which is also sometimes written $\setminus$.  If $A$ and $B$ are sets, then $A-B$ or $A\setminus B$ is defined as the set $\{x:x\in A\text{ and }x\not\in B\}$.  Since $\{0\}$ is the set whose only element is $0$, $\mathbb{Z}-\{0\}$ is the set of all integers except for $0$.  So $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}-\{0\}$ just means $a$ and $b$ are nonzero integers.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{Z}^*= \mathbb{Z}\backslash\{0\}=\mathbb{Z}-\{0\}$ : the set of all integers without $0$

Comment: The (correct) notation $\mathbb{Z}^\ast$ will most likely confuse the OP even more at this stage, espcially without more detail, since it requires the notion of group to be fully understood...

Comment: No it doesn't. The non-zero integers do not form a multiplicative group, anyway, and it's perfectly easy to accept that "$\mathbb{Z}^*$" is a notation that *means* non-zero integers without ever having heard of group theory.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs But without having learned group theory, the *origin* of this notation is obscure. Hence confusing: if the goal is to *help* the OP, explaining that origin should not take long, and would be good.

Comment: The origins of most notations are obscure. Elementary arithmetic does not begin with the origins of numerals and of the "plus" sign.

Comment: You are really playing devil's advocate, or misunderstanding what I say on purpose. The origin of **this** notation to denote sets with $0$ removed is absolutely not obscure: it comes directly from what is used in groups. Not mentioning it **makes** it obscure, which is *not* a good thing. @GTonyJacobs

Comment: I'm not misunderstanding you on purpose; you're very rude to presume that. I disagree with your claim that the answer "will most likely confuse the OP even more". Knowing that a certain notation means a certain thing doesn't require the notion of a group to be fully understood. Now, is this conversation worth continuing?

Comment: I agree with @GTonyJacobs, we already come across this notation on the secondary school. And we don't need to know the group theory, to understand the set of $\mathbb{Z}^*$ doesn't contain $0$